# Documentation for "ensureAuthentication" "isAuthenticated" passport's functions?

Tags: express, passport.js

I've been looking for a while, and can't see to find a definitive documentation source. When I search for these, the first Google results are to StackOverflow.

Are there any more middleware functions similar to this?

Answer (score 66, accepted):

While not explicitly documented anywhere easily found, you can see where the the `isAuthenticated` and `isUnauthenticated` flags are set in the Passport code at https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/a892b9dc54dce34b7170ad5d73d8ccfba87f4fcf/lib/passport/http/request.js#L74.

`ensureAuthenticated` is not official, but can be implemented via the following:

```js
function ensureAuthenticated(req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();
  else
    // Return error content: res.jsonp(...) or redirect: res.redirect('/login')
}

app.get('/account', ensureAuthenticated, function(req, res) {
  // Do something with user via req.user
});
```

Comment: The above example has a couple of issues.  Line 3 should be `if (req.isAuthenticated())`  and line 9 should be `..., ensureAuthenticated, ...`  Checkout the following for a better example. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/blob/master/examples/express3-mongoose/app.js

Comment: @chris Thanks for the note - I've corrected the issues above.

Comment: some documentation would be nice, as much fun as examining the source is

Comment: @ConnorLeech I'm not the author of Passport, but maybe you could try sending a pull request to [https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport)?

Comment: Updated example link -> https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-local/wiki/Examples

Answer (score 0):

the reason it return false is mostly because its declared below the route definition.
i am doing it in other file so i use it like this

```
//auth check
function auth(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        next();
    } 
    else{
        res.redirect("/fail");}
}

//routes
require("./routes/myroute")(app,auth);
```