# How to add user in DB when using Passport.js? How to modify existing routes to require authentication?

Tags: javascript, session, authentication, express, passport.js

Couple of questions. I set up authentication in my app using the following code:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done){
    Users.findOne({ username : username},function(err,user){
        if(err) { return done(err); }
        if(!user){
            return done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect username' });
        }

        hash( password, user.salt, function (err, hash) {
            if (err) { return done(err); }
            if (hash == user.hash) return done(null, user);
            done(null, false, { message: 'Incorrect password' });
        });
    });
}));

app.get('/admin', function (req, res){
    res.render('login.jade');
});

app.post('/admin', function (req, res){
    passport.authenticate('local', { successRedirect: '/main',
                                     failureRedirect: '/login',
                                     failureFlash: true });
});
```

Users is a DB schema that includes `username`, `password`, and `hash`.

The first and most obvious question is, how do I add a new user to the database? I specifically don't want a sign-up page but want to manually add every new user. Is there a way to do this manually?

Next, how do I modify my existing routes to only work if the user is authenticated? For example, I have:

```
app.get('/comment/:commentID', admin.renderComment);
```

The above `renderCommit` is a large handler function but accessing this page should only work if the user is authenticated. How do I check that?

Answer (score 0):

Creating a new user should be relatively straightforward, from a standalone script for instance:

```
// Load your models, set up database connection, etc.
...
// Create a new user:
Users.create({
  username : USERNAME,
  password : HASHED_PASSWORD,
  salt     : GENERATED_SALT,
}, function(err, user) {
  if (err) {
    console.error('Error creating user:', err.message);
  } else {
    console.log('User created successfully');
  }
});
```

As for making sure that a user is logged in when certain routes are requested, you can use [a simple middleware for that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14301657/893780):

```
app.get('/comment/:commentID', ensureAuthenticated, admin.renderComment);
```