# Change view based on user role with MEAN + Passport

Tags: angularjs, node.js, authentication, mongoose, passport.js

I'm setting up an authentication scheme with the MEAN stack and PassportJS to authenticate a user via an OpenID provider. When a user is not authenticated, I display a link that redirects the user to the OpenID provider. After authentication, I want to replace the link with some text along the lines of  "Welcome {user}".

Currently, I am able to perform the authentication and store the returned identifier as such:

```
passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  done(null, user.identifier);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function(id, done) {
  User.findByIdAndUpdate(id, {}, { upsert: true }, function(err, user) {
    done(err, user);
  });
});
```

*(Am I implementing my serialize and deserialize functions correctly?)*

From this, the user id is stored as a cookie and also as a key in the database.  Now in my client-side code, what would be the best way to change the view (sign-in -> welcome text) based on whether user has been authenticated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether the user is authentication on the server side using

```
req.isAuthenticated()
```

Call this value in your server side code and pass the result to your view or to the client side code in some other manner, a separate ajax call to the server if necessary. This comes from PassportJS

- https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport/blob/a892b9dc54dce34b7170ad5d73d8ccfba87f4fcf/lib/passport/http/request.js#L74

Found in this answer:
[Documentation for "ensureAuthentication" "isAuthenticated" passport's functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14188834/express-passport-where-is-the-documentation-for-ensureauthentication-isaut)

Comment: Once I am able to tell if a user is authenticated on the client side, what would be a good solution to changing the view?

Answer (score 1):

Your `seriliazeUser` and `deserializeUser` functions look ok.

As far as I remember there is some code in mean stack that sets `window.user` after user is authenticated, and there is also a [`Global`](https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/public/js/services/global.js) service on angular side that uses this information to set `authenticated` value. You can use that information to alter your view.

Take a look at Header controller code.

https://github.com/linnovate/mean/blob/master/public/js/controllers/header.js