# How do I password protect a folder with Node.js and Express?

Tags: html, node.js, express, web, static

I'm making a simple web server with Node.js and Express. I'm hosting many static files, including a Unity WebGL game.

For the game to work properly, many assets need to be loaded. Is there some kind of easy way I could store a cookie with a password (on a login page), and if the password cookie is present and has the right value, all requests are accepted?

Still very new to web server stuff, all I've done so far is Discord bots.

So basically all I'm trying to do is have a simple password page (and maybe have some kind of a delay when it checks if the password is correct) and then let you load things in one folder.

Hope that's easy to do. Sorry if my question is dumb.

Comment: This might help:
[Documentation for Auth](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14301657/16010779)

Comment: I'm not using passport.js and it seems to use user systems, I'm just looking to have a password, no username

Comment: just to gather more info - you are creating a unity game which will call a nodejs/express API for authentication - this nodejs/express API will respond back with static files after successful authentication, and load files into the unity game correct?

Comment: If so, I suggest learning about JWT tokens, have a express route that validates the password and returns a JWT token, require the JWT token in every request to retrieve static files as a header in the request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Setting a cookie

to set a cookie you can use something like expresses cookie-parser middle-ware check it [here](https://github.com/expressjs/cookie-parser)

### Giving access

you can send some kind of **uuid** or **access token** from the client side using something like **fetch api** or an ordinary **XMLHttpRequest**
refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/247483/http-get-request-in-javascript)
and use some logic to give access to the file

### code

```
var express = require('express')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')

var app = express()
app.use(cookieParser())

app.get('/getfile', (req, res) => {
    const code = req.cookies.mysecertcode;
    if(code = secert) {
         res.send("correct token")
    } else {
         res.send("incorrect token")
    }

})

app.listen(8080)
```

*this code is just a simple code I made you can use your own*

**Hope this can help you thank you**

Comment: thanks so much, i've started implementing this and its exactly what i was looking for